# docker websphere can't get the admin console

Tags: docker, console, websphere, admin

I am running WebSphere on docker. When I expose the port 9080, I can get the "Welcome to Liberty" page(http://localhost:9080).

```
docker run -d -e LICENSE=accept -p 9080:9080  docker.io/websphere-liberty
```

> CONTAINER ID: 1d1eb3db6b03        
>   IMAGE:docker.io/websphere-liberty
>   COMMAND:"/opt/ibm/wlp/bin/ser"
>   CREATED:17 seconds ago
>   STATUS:Up 15 seconds
>   PORTS:9443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9080->9080/tcp
>                               NAMES: naughty_ritchie

Here is the issue. When I expose the port 9060. I couldn't get the admin console page (http://localhost:9060/admin). Any suggestions?

```
docker run -d -e LICENSE=accept -p 9060:9060  docker.io/websphere-liberty
```

> CONTAINER ID: 8d9cc97d2656        
>   IMAGE:docker.io/websphere-liberty
>   COMMAND:"/opt/ibm/wlp/bin/ser"
>   CREATED:4 minutes ago
>   STATUS:Up 4 minutes
>   PORTS: 9080/tcp, 9443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9060->9060/tcp
>   NAMES:thirsty_hodgkin

Comment: What specifically happens when you access the console? Connection refused? HTTP error? Redirected to another port?

Comment: I got the below message from the curl command:                                              curl http://localhost:9060/admin
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer. Nothing printed on logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Created an image with adminCenter
   `FROM websphere-liberty
   RUN installUtility install adminCenter-1.0 --acceptLicense
   COPY server.xml /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/
   ENV LICENSE accept
   EXPOSE 80 9080 9448 9443 9060`
2. In the server.xml, put adminCenter-1.0 in the feature of featuremanager.
   `

Answer (score 1):

Based on your URL and port, you're trying to access the WebSphere "traditional" admin console on a WebSphere Liberty Profile server.  If you want a UI, have a look at the Admin Center feature:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_ui.html

You'd also need to expose more ports for both normal operation and the admin center itself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the adminCenter. I installed the adminCenter-1.0. And put the server.xml as `<server description="Default Server">
    <featureManager>
  <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
...
</server>` I got the **context root not found**. Any more suggestions @covener

Comment: What URL? Usually the messages.log/console.log tells you where it thinks each app is available as they start

Comment: if you're trying to reach the admin center, the URL would be something like this:  localhost:9080/adminCenter

Please note that's a UI, so you can't CURL that one.

Comment: @covener @ArthurDM the URL is **https://localhost:9443/adminCenter **. It then returns the ** context root not found**. I am trying to find the logs. But after entering inside the container, I only see old logs. Do you know why? `root@6468e50db807:/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs# date
Fri May 13 18:19:23 UTC 2016
root@6468e50db807:/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs# ls -lrt
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1765 Apr  7 09:56 messages_16.04.07_09.57.02.0.log
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    6 Apr  7 09:57 state
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1765 Apr  7 09:57 messages.log`

Comment: are you exposing that port?